# Initialize a Object having multiple Object as Properties

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class as

```
public class Root
    {
        public Child1 child1 { get; set; }
        public Child2 child2 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Child1
    {
        public Grandchild grandChild { get; set; }
    }
    public class Grandchild
    {
        public string a { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to get the output in json as

```
{
    "Child1": {
        "Grandchild": {
            "a": ""
        }
    },
    "Child2":{...}
}
```

I am having a constraint of not using a constructor, is there a better way instead of manually initializing each and every class?

Have tried using a contactResolver but from that only till child1 and child2 are getting initializd

```
{
    "Child1": {
        "Grandchild": null
    },
    "Child2":{...}
}
```

If I serialize new Root() then I will get the json as

```
{
"Child1" : null,
"Child2": null
}
```

Is there a way without defining the constructor to get the expected output?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here

Comment: so you're asking how to build an object tree, that can be serialized to json?